# DataColumn.Expression, сложение строк выдает пустую строку

Tags: c#, база-данных, access, oledb

Есть таблица с полями

```
[Фамилия], [Имя], [Отчество]
```

Создаю вычисляемое поле `[Полное имя]`, в свойстве `Expression` задаю сложение строк

```
[Фамилия]+' '+[Имя]+' '+[Отчество]
```

Если все поля имеют значение всё работает нормально, но если хоть одно поле пустое, то результат равен пустой строке. Почему? Как тогда сделать сложение строк в Expression?

База создана в Access, но вычисляемое поле и другие свойства я задаю в схеме данных объекта DataSet (Visual Studio 2017, C#).

```
DataTable.DataColumn.Expression = " [Фамилия]+' '+[Имя]+' '+[Отчество]"
```

Comment: Это Access? Укажите где Вы задаете выражение.

Comment: В схеме данных. Да, база создана в Access, но вычисляемое поле и другие свойства я задаю в схеме данных объекта DataSet. Напрямую DataTable.DataColumn.Expression = " [Фамилия]+' '+[Имя]+' '+[Отчество]";

Comment: Добавьте Ваши уточнения из комментариев непосредственно в текст вопроса, это ускорит получения ответа, ибо люди ленивы и не факт, что прочитав вопрос, они будут читать комментарии :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если одно из значений в сумме равно `NULL`, то и результат будет `NULL`.

В документации [`DataColumn.Expression`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.8) указана функция `ISNULL`, которую можно использовать:

```
  DataTable.DataColumn.Expression = "ISNULL([Фамилия], '')+' '+ISNULL([Имя],'')+' '+ISNULL([Отчество],'')";
```

Так, если например, `[Имя]` не будет заполнено, то оно будет принято за пустую строку.

Comment: Опередили - от меня "+" :)